# How to increment the index of a list for saving the next number in next index of list

Tags: c#

I want to save the result of `zarb` function which repeats for 1000 times in a list with size 1000. Then I must to increase the index of the list for every calculation to avoid to save the next calculation at the same index of previous one. How can I do that?

```
var results = new List<float>(1000);
for (int z = 0; z < 1000; z++)
{
   results.Add(zarb(sc,z));
   //increase the index of resukts
}
foreach (var resultwithindex in results.Select((r, index) => new { result = r, Index = index }).OrderByDescending(r => r.result).Take(20))
{
   MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}: {1}", resultwithindex.Index, resultwithindex.result));
}
```

Zarb function

```
public float zarb(int userid, int itemid)
        {

            float[] u_f = a[userid];
            float[] i_f = b[itemid];

            for (int i = 0; i < u_f.Length; i++)
            {

                result += u_f[i] * i_f[i];

            }
            return result;

        }
```

Comment: you dont need to increase the index explicitly like an array.

Comment: This question would better be addressed using a full code sample. Probably not a problem with List. May be better as "Why is the return value of my method including the sum of previous method calls?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't. The `Add` method (surprisingly) *adds* an item into the list. It doesn't replace anything. You should [read MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `List<T>`. Also, don't be afraid of trying and seeing the results before asking—you'll save time.

Comment: Okey @OndrejTucny . when I run it,it adds all the previous numbers to the next one.For example if the numbers are 1,2,4,5,9,10,17,.... when the process finish the output is like 1,3,7,12,21,.... (it sums the all previous numbers and add to the current index) while the output must be like 1,2,4,5,9,10,..  I edited the code and add the zarb function to it

Comment: Based on this information, it appears you're not having a problem with the List. You're probably using "result" as a field in the class, which means the value will persist through method calls. Do you instead intend to have float result = 0.0 at the beginning of the method?

Comment: Without seeing the code (perhaps you could edit the question) -- it's hard to say what "result" is. I'm guessing this is a field at the class level, rather than a variable at the method level. Do you ever need "result" outside of zarb? Why does zarb affect a value defined elsewhere, rather than use the return value? --- If "result" can't be affected, try adding a "float retVal = 0.0;" to the top of the method, usages of result to "retVal", and change "return result;" to "result += retVal; return retVal;".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand the question, but you do not need index for list. The add method will deal with the it.